# Where to register domain event handlers in c# class library DLL

Tags: c#, events, domain-driven-design

I have a solution set up like so:

- Solution

  1. Visual Basic ASP.NET Web Application (.NET4)
  2. C# Class Library (.NET2)

The class library DLL is included as a reference in the web application.

The class library makes extensive use of domain driven architecture.  Now, I'm in the process of adding domain events, in the way of [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/).

```
public static class DomainEvents
{ 
    [ThreadStatic] //so that each thread has its own callbacks
    private static List<Delegate> actions;

    public static IContainer Container { get; set; } //as before

    //Registers a callback for the given domain event
    public static void Register<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        if (actions == null)
            actions = new List<Delegate>();

            actions.Add(callback);
    }

    //Clears callbacks passed to Register on the current thread
    public static void ClearCallbacks ()
    {
        actions = null;
    }

    //Raises the given domain event
    public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
    if (Container != null)
        foreach(var handler in Container.ResolveAll<Handles<T>>())
            handler.Handle(args);

    if (actions != null)
        foreach (var action in actions)
            if (action is Action<T>)
                ((Action<T>)action)(args);
    }
}
```

I need to register my domain event handlers in the class library.  There is no `global.asax` for a class library, so I cannot make use of `Application_Start`.  Where is the best place to register domain event handlers in a class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is responsible for glueing everything together.

You either hook everything up on `Application_Start` or you invoke a function in the class library from there that registers your handlers.

```
new Bootstrapper().Bootstrap();
```